# How to start debugging this Java error?

Tags: java, eclipse, mule

I'm a student in eclipse, java, and mule.  I'm getting an error when trying to Run As--> Mule Server and have no idea what the problem could be.  Any suggestions?   Much thanks for any advice!!!

```
INFO  2011-05-20 12:00:59,425 [main] org.mule.MuleServer: Mule Server initializing...
ERROR 2011-05-20 12:00:59,785 [main] org.mule.MuleServer: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : and (java.io.FileNotFoundException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-12999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. and (java.io.FileNotFoundException)
  org.mule.config.ConfigResource:35 (null)
2. and (java.io.FileNotFoundException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
  org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder:96 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/config/ConfigurationException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: and
    at org.mule.config.ConfigResource.<init>(ConfigResource.java:35)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.loadConfigResources(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.<init>(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2011-05-20 12:00:59,800 [main] org.mule.MuleServer: 
********************************************************************************
* A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* and (java.io.FileNotFoundException)                                          *
*                                                                              *
* The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that it always helps to cut & paste error messages into Google to see who else has experienced my pain.

When I do that for yours, I get this:

http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Error-in-Hello-Example-td2677866.html

Comment: this is an important lesson :)

Comment: Hmm I've seen this too.  How do you verify which workspace you are working in?

Comment: @MByD - Yes, it is. And I was surprised when I realised how many developers don't know it.

Comment: Does you install directory path have spaces in it?  If yes, don't come back until you re-install.  ("Program Files" - avoid it.)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, with Mule 3.1.2 spaces in the path should be ok (although I personally discourage it any day, who knows which lib fails next), and MULE_HOME env variable is no longer required. In fact it is advised to remove one if set. Give it a try, 3.1.2 is coming out any day now.